# Iterating upon Variable From Database Entry using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to set it up so that every time the API query entry in the database it iterates `1` to a value named `Popularity`, contained inside of that entry.

I have set it up so that it finds the entry then gets ready to edit the `Popularity` value. Is this the right approach?

```
router.get("/:ItemID", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updateditem = await Items.findOneAndUpdate(
      { ItemID: req.params.ItemID },
      {
        $set: {
          Popularity: //Previous Value of POPULARITY + 1
        }
      }
    );
    res.json(updateditem);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Creating your Schema, you just have to update your model in every API hit by using `mongoose` inc Query

```
    Items.findOneAndUpdate(
      { ItemID: req.params.ItemID },
      { $inc: { Popularity: 1 } },
      { new: true },
     function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         callback(err);
       } else {
         callback(response);
       }
     }
   );
```

or in your code:

```
    router.get("/:ItemID", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const updateditem = await Items.findOneAndUpdate(
          { ItemID: req.params.ItemID },
          { $inc: { Popularity: 1 } },
          { new: true },
        );
        res.json(updateditem);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.